# How to migrate a private Bitbucket repository to a public Github repository

Tags: github, bitbucket

How can I migrate a private Bitbucket repository to a public Github repository?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Make a "bare" clone of the repository (i.e. a full copy of the data, but without a working directory for editing files) using the external clone URL. This ensures a clean, fresh export of all the old data.
2. Push the local cloned repository to GitHub using the "mirror" option, which ensures that all references (i.e. branches, tags, etc.) are copied to the imported repository.

Here are all the commands:

```
git clone --bare https://bitbucket.com/user/repo.git
cd repo.git
git push --mirror https://github.com/ghuser/repo.git
```

Comment: Thanks for this simple yet effective answer. I wrote [this shell script](https://gist.github.com/mhulse/6e32f1a5b403ec8438186f52e9bfc3c6) (inspired by this answer) to transfer multiple repos from Bitbucket to GitHub (should work in reverse too). Anyway, +1